# Email form yields empty $_POST upon submit

Tags: php, html, email

So with this PHP code below, Im trying to send an email. for some reason, when I click the submit button on my html contact page, the php gets both errors,

`Error: all fields are required
Error: Invalid email address`

and I know its a proper email and all the fields are filled out, im 99% sure all the input fields are properly names in the HTML file.. here's the PHP code

```
<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'support@Blocked for security.host22.com';//<-----Put Your email address here.
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['email']) || 
   empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 

if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $myemail; 
    $email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
    " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Message \n $message"; 

    $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
} 
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contact form handler</title>
</head>

<body>
<!-- This page is displayed only if there is some error -->
<?php
echo nl2br($errors);
?>


</body>
</html>
```

the HTML of the form:

```
            <form action="contact-form-handler.php" method="POST" enctype="text/plain" name="contactform">
            <label for='name'>Name:</label><br/><input type="text" name="name"><br/>
            <label for='email'>Email:</label><br/><input type="text" name="email"><br/>
            <label for='message'>Message:</label><br/><textarea name="message" cols=48 rows=4></textarea><br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
        </form>
```

Comment: Could you just add the output of `var_dump($_POST)` and maybe the HTML form that goes with it?

Comment: Check whether you have mentioned method="POST" in your from declaration in HTML.

Comment: Add you can use `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` to validate email instead of writing custom expressions...

Comment: I figured out the error, its not getting the value of name email and message.. Im new to PHP, how would I do that?

Comment: @Chris Show the form HTML as well, perhaps the parameters are sent via GET?

Comment: I did, I honestly dont know much of anything about PHP.. i still need to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your form is here:

```
enctype="text/plain"
```

For PHP to put the variables into `$_POST` the `enctype` should either be removed or be equal to either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.

Answer (score 0):

So the email address !preg_match. I personally wouldn't bother trying to use regexes in an attempt to validate that people are inputting real email addresses, you'll end up with that validation from SMTP itself.

At least for now just remove this section of your code:

```
if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
$errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}
```

Then rerun your script and you will know that the regex was the issue. Hopefully you are using this script in a way that people really want to get the email you are sending. If that is the case, the most I would make anyone bother with is maybe to verify the email address by entering it twice in the form maybe?

Comment: still, Im checking if im getting any input from the fields, but i'm not.. how do i get the text of the field?

Comment: Obviously, the message `Error: all fields are required` is the first problem that should be fixed.

Comment: exactly what I'm trying to do.